# How to add values to a Map?

Tags: trigger, map

This is my code:

```
If(OppLineItems.size() > 0) 
    {
        insert OppLineItems;

        for(OpportunityLineItem OppLI : OppLineItems)
        {
            Map<Account, List<OpportunityLineItem>> dealerships = new Map <Account, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
            dealerships.put(OppLI.Dealership__c, OppLI);
            system.debug('Dealerships' + dealerships);
            List<Opportunity> OppsToCreate = new List<Opportunity>();
            Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
            for(Account dealership : dealerships.keyset())
            {
                //Create new Opportunities and add fields
                newOpp.Name = ' Child Opportunity';
                newOpp.Account = dealership;
                newOpp.CloseDate = Date.today(); 
                newOpp.StageName = 'Prospecting';

                OppsToCreate.add(newOpp);
            }

            if(OppsToCreate.size() > 0)
            {
                insert OppsToCreate;
            }
        }
```

I want to go through each Dealership which is a lookup to account(dealership__c) on OpportunityLineItem and create a new Opportunity for all the OpportunityLineItems belonging to it.

But I don't know how to add the values in to the map. I am getting this error: Incompatible key type Id for Map> When I try to say `dealerships.put(OppLI.Dealership__c, OppLI);` leading me to think I am putting the incorrect key and values in here?

Comment: Hi nik, 
Take your map as Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> dealerships = new Map <Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();

Since you are putting id in the key and not the object.

Comment: Thanks Ruchi I had tried that originally but I got this error now: Incompatible value type OpportunityLineItem for Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>> even though OppLineItems is a List?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, the keys and values are not compatible with your map.

Given:

```
Map<Account, List<OpportunityLineItem>> dealerships = new Map <Account, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
```

The map is expecting you to put into it an `Account` key, and a List of `OpportunityLineItems` as a value.

However, when you do this:

```
dealerships.put(OppLI.Dealership__c, OppLI);
```

You're giving it an `ID` key, and a single `OpportunityLineItem` value.

If you want your map to store these, you need to change it to the following:

```
Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> dealerships = new Map <Id, OpportunityLineItem>();
```

Alternatively, if the values do need to be lists of `OpportunityLineItems`, you need to check whether the map `containsKey(OppLI.Dealership__c)`.  If so, `get(OppLI.Dealership__c)` to return the existing list of `OpportunityLineItems`, add the `OppLI` to this list, and then `put` the updated list in the map with `OppLI.Dealership__c` as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting single record in map value which is expecting list

try

```
dealerships.put(OppLI.Dealership__c, new List<OpportunityLineItem>{oppLI});
```